# Como ter apenas uma adapter para várias Activity?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber se de alguma forma ou é recomendado ter uma *adapter* para cada *Activity*.

Sei que fazer com uma *Adapter* para cada *Activity* é tranquilo.

Agora como fazer uma *Adapter* genérica, teria como?

Estaria seguindo os padrões de projeto?

## Minha Activity

```java
public class CardapioPizzaria extends Activity {

    ListView listViewCardapio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardapio_pizzaria);

        this.listViewCardapio = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCardapio);

        CardapioAdapter cardapioAdapter = new CardapioAdapter(this);
        this.listViewCardapio.setAdapter(cardapioAdapter);

    }
}
```

## Adapter

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;

    /*Construtor*/
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Bom Filé","3214 - 2435")); 
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Porcão","3214 - 2435"));
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Palmarys","3214 - 2435")); 
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Fat Boy","3217 - 2452")); 
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Fratelli","3215 - 5010")); 
       listArray.add(new DataModel("Pizza Paulista","3214 - 3271")); 
        listArray.add(new DataModel("Fogão a Lenha","3215 - 5168")); 
       listArray.add(new DataModel("Alô Pizza","3214 - 4193")); 
    }

    /**Total de elementos dentro do array */
    public int getCount() {
        return listArray.size();
    }

    /**Pegando o item da lista */
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listArray.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_lista, parent, false);
        }

        final DataModel dataModel = listArray.get(index);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome_estabelecimento);
        textView.setText(dataModel.getName());

        TextView textViewTelefone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numeroTelefone);
        textViewTelefone.setText("" + dataModel.getTelefone());

        Button buttonLigar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ligar_pizza);
        Button buttonVerCardapio = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ver_cardapio_pizza);

        buttonLigar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri url = Uri.parse("tel: " + dataModel.getTelefone());
                Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,url);
                context.startActivity(it);    
            }
        });

        buttonVerCardapio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent it = new Intent(context, CardapioPizzaria.class);
                context.startActivity(it);   
            }
        });

       return view;
    }
}
```

Não coloquei os *layouts* pois não vi necessidade.

Comment: Não há problema nenhum em compartilhar uma mesma classe de `Adapter` para várias `Activity`. Ou você quis dizer instância? É muito comum aproveitar classes caso seja benéfico (não adianta compartilhar se começar a ficar muito complexo ou confuso)... Isso é bem subjetivo, vai variar de projeto para projeto.

Comment: você teria um exemplo desse compartilhamento???

Comment: Por exemplo eu no meu projeto tenho duas *Activity's* com duas listas de coisas diferentes. Mas as listas são tão parecidas que uso o mesmo *Adapter* para as duas listas. Se tiveres de fazer muitas alterações do *Adapter* para ser genérico então estás a reaproveitar e sim a complicar.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que entendi sua dúvida. Atualmente você tem os itens sendo criados no seu adapter, porém você quer usar o mesmo adapter com itens diferentes. Se for isso, basta você passar a lista de elementos no construtor do seu adapter, quando você for utilizar o adapter em outra tela, basta passar a sua lista de elementos fazendo com o que seu adapter seja fácil de reutilizar, exemplo:

```
/*Construtor*/
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DataModel> elements) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listArray = elements;
    }
```

Na sua Activity:

```
     public class CardapioPizzaria extends Activity {

            ListView listViewCardapio;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardapio_pizzaria);

                this.listViewCardapio = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCardapio);

                CardapioAdapter cardapioAdapter = new CardapioAdapter(this,getList());
                this.listViewCardapio.setAdapter(cardapioAdapter);

            }

       private ArrayList<DataModel> getList(){

            ArrayList<DataModel> listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Bom Filé","3214 - 2435")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Porcão","3214 - 2435"));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Palmarys","3214 - 2435")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Fat Boy","3217 - 2452")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Fratelli","3215 - 5010")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Pizza Paulista","3214 - 3271")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Fogão a Lenha","3215 - 5168")); 
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Alô Pizza","3214 - 4193")); 
            return listArray;
       }
}
```

Dessa forma você só precisa ter a lista que necessitar na sua activity para cada adapter.